# Semaphores for different parts of the same shared memory block in C

Tags: c, memory, multiprocessing, semaphore, shared-memory

I have a question on how to set up a shared memory segment for my program.

In my program I want to have a main structure to contain 50 different accounts. 
Something that looks like this.

```
struct list{
   struct account[50];
};
```

Within each account there is just some basic info

```
struct account{
   int x;
   char * y;
};
```

Now, I want my entire list to be located in a shared memory segment as different child processes of my main process will be updating different accounts in the list.

However, I only want a child process to be able to access a certain account in this list. How exactly would I go about setting up a shared memory segment that can be locked down by a child process in different parts? For example, I want a semaphore that can lock down access to account[32] in the shared memory segment. This means that another process could be updating account[29] in the shared memory segment at the same time with no problem.

I am not really looking for concrete code examples (although those would be helpful), but more of a conceptual understanding of the best way to set up shared memory for this program.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what this is about, I see two alternatives:

The first one is to modify `struct account`, so there's one extra field, a semaphore. Any process should `P()` on the semaphore before it accesses the other account's fields, and `V()` when it's done with it.

The second would be to modify `struct list`, adding an extra array of semaphores, same size as the array of accounts, assigning each semaphore in the array with the same-indexed account, and using `P()` and `V()` on it again, before and after accessing the corresponding account.

Comment: In both cases, you should be extremely careful of false sharing (having several semaphores in the same cache line). You could add some padding to avoid that.

Comment: yes, I think this would work. However, I also want a way to read all the information in the accounts every 30 seconds and print it out regardless of whether a certain process is updating an account at the moment. Which approach would be better if I want this to happen? How would I quickly transfer control from the child process (which updates the account) to the parent which should print out all the information of all accounts at that point in time? Or do I not need a transfer of control and can have the parent process looking at this shared memory segment the entire time. Thank you

Comment: @JesterKynes: I'm not sure I understood the part about transfer control, but I guess no other process should be able to access the account while it's being updated, or else what would be the point of synchronization at all?

Comment: So I want to be able to lock down the whole list struct at one time for a method that can print all its information. if an account is getting updated this time , how do i transfer control of the shared memory to the print info function and then transfer it back to the update account function once the print info function is finished.  In other words, I think I want two layers of authorization. If the list is currently locked by the print function, I want all the accounts that are being updated to be locked until the print function is done. Then I want the accounts to be unlocked

Comment: @JesterKynes: If you want to snapshot the entire data set, you need to lock the entire data set. You can obtain each and every semaphore, or you can create a shared read/write lock. To read from the data set, a process must obtain a read lock. To write anywhere in the data set, the process must obtain a write lock -on the entire data set. If you don't do it that way, you can't be assured of getting a view of the list as it exists at any one instant in time.. You should drop the semaphores for individual data elements if you do that.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense. Thank you all